# Como somar elementos de duas lista de vetores com if C++

Tags: array, c++, lista, if

Bom estou travado nesse programa faz bom tempo. Sou inciante e o objetivo da questão é fazer operações entre cada elemento de duas listas se o resto for 1, 2 e assim vai.
Exemplo: 2 lista com elementos, `4 9 7` e `1 2 3`, você vai somar `4+1` se a divisão `4/4` for igual a zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, i, j, s =0, resto = 0;
  

  cin >> n;

  int vet[n], resultado[n];
  
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){

    cin >> vet[i];
  }

  for (j=0; j<n; j++){

    cin >> vet[j];
  }

  for (i=0; i<n; i++){ 

    resto = vet[i] % 4;
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){ 
        if (resto == 0){
          resultado[i] = vet[i]+vet[j];
        }
        if (resto == 1){
          resultado[i] = vet[i]-vet[j];
        }
        if (resto == 2){
          resultado[i] = vet[i]*vet[j];
        }
        if (resto == 3){
          resultado[i] = vet[i]/vet[j];
        }
        if (resto == 4){
          resultado[i] = vet[i]^vet[j];
        }
    }
    cout << resultado[i] << ' ';
     
  }
}
```

Comment: Quando que a divisão `4/4` é igual a zero? No código `if (resto == 0){` por que somar `vet[i]` com `vet[j]` já que a única forma de `resto` ser igual a zero é se `vet[i]` for zero?

Answer (score 0):

Oi, aconselho a aprender e usar sempre os sub-idiomas de C++ moderno:

Exemplo: [corilu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cc49e48921b2171)

use std::copy_n para ler as entradas

```
copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), n, std::back_inserter(v1)); // le 'n' números em v1
```

use std::transform para percorrer e alterar o vetor

```
transform( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), ... );
```

use std::vector a 'auto' sempre que possível

```
 vector<int> v1,v2;
```

use lambdas para expressar as funções

```
 auto x = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

E por favor, poste a parte importante do código aqui ( como eu fiz acima ) e o código completo no compiler explorer ou corilu.

Abraços